# What is the id number for Brotli compression inside a ZIP archive?

Tags: zip, brotli

The ZIP file format supports a number of compression algorithms and assigns them numbers, for example 0 is store, 8 is deflate, and 14 is lzma. What number indicates Brotli compression? Is there any additional zip-level metadata needed for this compression algorithm?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on `Zip (file format)` does not mention Brotli as a supported compression method.  Are you sure it's supported?

Comment: I'm confident that when it is supported someone will answer this question.

Comment: Update: now that zstd has a number, no longer need ZIP with Brotli!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this writing, there isn't one. The official list of ZIP file format compression methods is found in [PKWare's ZIP Appnote](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), for which the most recent version is 6.3.4, dated October 1, 2014. Here are the defined compression methods therein:

```
   4.4.5 compression method: (2 bytes)

        0 - The file is stored (no compression)
        1 - The file is Shrunk
        2 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 1
        3 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 2
        4 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 3
        5 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 4
        6 - The file is Imploded
        7 - Reserved for Tokenizing compression algorithm
        8 - The file is Deflated
        9 - Enhanced Deflating using Deflate64(tm)
       10 - PKWARE Data Compression Library Imploding (old IBM TERSE)
       11 - Reserved by PKWARE
       12 - File is compressed using BZIP2 algorithm
       13 - Reserved by PKWARE
       14 - LZMA (EFS)
       15 - Reserved by PKWARE
       16 - Reserved by PKWARE
       17 - Reserved by PKWARE
       18 - File is compressed using IBM TERSE (new)
       19 - IBM LZ77 z Architecture (PFS)
       97 - WavPack compressed data
       98 - PPMd version I, Rev 1
```

I suppose you could define your own method number and use it, but that use would be non-standard. (It is a two-byte field, so you could pick a large number that PKWare would be very unlikely to define to be something else.)

No, there is no other information required to be able to decompress a brotli stream.

*Update:*

As of the July 2020 appnote (6.3.9), more compression methods, notably zstd and xz, but still no brotli.

```
   4.4.5 compression method: (2 bytes)

        0 - The file is stored (no compression)
        1 - The file is Shrunk
        2 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 1
        3 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 2
        4 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 3
        5 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 4
        6 - The file is Imploded
        7 - Reserved for Tokenizing compression algorithm
        8 - The file is Deflated
        9 - Enhanced Deflating using Deflate64(tm)
       10 - PKWARE Data Compression Library Imploding (old IBM TERSE)
       11 - Reserved by PKWARE
       12 - File is compressed using BZIP2 algorithm
       13 - Reserved by PKWARE
       14 - LZMA
       15 - Reserved by PKWARE
       16 - IBM z/OS CMPSC Compression
       17 - Reserved by PKWARE
       18 - File is compressed using IBM TERSE (new)
       19 - IBM LZ77 z Architecture 
       20 - deprecated (use method 93 for zstd)
       93 - Zstandard (zstd) Compression 
       94 - MP3 Compression 
       95 - XZ Compression 
       96 - JPEG variant
       97 - WavPack compressed data
       98 - PPMd version I, Rev 1
       99 - AE-x encryption marker (see APPENDIX E)
```